# Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$ then it has a left hand limit at $b$

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to start with $\epsilon> 0$, and with $f$ uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$, so then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $x,u \in (a,b)$ with $|x - u|<δ$ then $|f(x)-f(u)|<\epsilon$.  Since $x,u < b$ then $b-x >0$ so we have $0 < b - x <\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(b)|<\epsilon$. I'm not sure with this idea because $b$ is not in the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: The function $f$ can be not defined at $b$ or if $f(b)$ exists it can be different of $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to b^{-}} f(x)}$. Take as an example $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\;x<1\\0&\text{if }\; x=1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  First show $f$ is bounded.  It follows that there must be a lim sup $f(x)$ and lim inf $f(x)$ as $x\to b$.  Suppose lim sup > lim inf, which has  to happen if there is no limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to b$.  Choose $\epsilon={1\over 2}(\limsup - \liminf)$.  For some $\delta$ we must have $|f(u)-f(v)|<\epsilon$ for $u,v\in (b-\delta,b)$.  This means $\limsup-\liminf<\epsilon$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

By uniform continuity, there is a positive sequence $\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3 \cdots$ going to $0$ such that whenever $x,y \in (b - \delta_k, b)$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{k}$. Note that the definition with $\leq$ and that with $<$ are both equivalent.

In other words, the image of $f$, let's call it $I_k$, in $(b - \delta_k, b)$ is a subset of a closed interval $C_k$ of length $\frac 1k$. It's easy to see that $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \cdots $ and furthermore the length of the intervals goes to $0$, hence by the nested interval theorem $\bigcap C_k$ has precisely one element, let's call it $L$.

A consequence of this is that any $x \in (b - \delta_k, b)$ satisfies $f(x) \in C_k$. Since $L \in C_k$, and the length of $C_k$  is $\frac{1}{k}$, we can see that $|f(x) - L| \leq \frac{1}{k}$.

Since $\frac{1}{k}$ can be made smaller than any given $\epsilon > 0$, this completes the proof.